# how i can update inventory with typeORM, nestjs and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nestjs, node.js-typeorm

how can I execute this kind of query with MongoDB typeORM

```
return await this.inventoryRepository.update(
      { id },
      { $inc: { totalInventory: -1 } },
    );
```

same query is working in the mongodb shell :

```
db.inventory.findOneAndUpdate({id:"someidhere"},{ $inc: {totalInventory: -1}});
```

but in nextjs service it is giving me an error :

```
Argument of type '{ $inc: { totalInventory: number; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QueryDeepPartialEntity<Inventory>'.
```

Comment: Why dont you use mongoose instead? @nestjs/mongoose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i mange this with the following code :

```
async updateInventory(id: string, dif: number) {
    const manager = getMongoManager();

    try {
      return await manager.findOneAndUpdate(
        Inventory,
        { id },
        { $inc: { totalInventory: dif } },
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```